# Loop to List file names in range of cells (A12 - A41) then finish listing file names on sheet 2 in another Range (A10 - A200) VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have been searching the other topics, but haven't been able to work this out. Right now this code works but, I want it to only list the files in sheet 1 cells A12-A41, then I want it to finish listing the files on sheet 2 A10-A200.
This is what I have so far.

```
Dim iRow
Dim F_File As Object
Dim Ac_Fi As Acrobat.AcroPDDoc

Sub ListFiles()
    iRow = 12
    Call ListMyFiles(Range("D3"))
End Sub

Sub ListMyFiles(mySourcePath)
    Set Myobject = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set mysource = Myobject.GetFolder(mySourcePath)
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim P1 As Double
    Dim P2 As Double

    For Each Myfile In mysource.Files
        If InStr(1, Myfile.Name, ".eps") Then
            iCol = 1
            'Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = myFile.Path
            'iCol = iCol + 1
            Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = Myfile.Name
            iCol = iCol + 10
            Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = "1"
            'iCol = iCol + 1
            'Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = myFile.Size
            'iCol = iCol + 1
            'Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = myFile.DateLastModified
            iRow = iRow + 1
        End If
    Next

    For Each Myfile In mysource.Files
        If InStr(1, Myfile.Name, ".pdf") Then
            Set Ac_Fi = New Acrobat.AcroPDDoc
            Ac_Fi.Open Myfile
            iCol = 1
            Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = Myfile.Name
            iCol = iCol + 10
            Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = Ac_Fi.GetNumPages
            'iCol = iCol + 1
            'Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = myFile.Size
            'iCol = iCol + 1
            'Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = myFile.DateLastModified
            Set PDFPage = Ac_Fi.AcquirePage(0).GetSize()

            P1 = Format(PDFPage.y / 72, "#.###")
            P2 = Format(PDFPage.x / 72, "#.###")
            iCol = iCol + 2

            If P2 < P1 Then
                Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = P2 & " x " & P1
            Else
                Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = P1 & " x " & P2
            End If

            iRow = iRow + 1
            Ac_Fi.Close
            Set Ac_Fi = Nothing
        End If
    Next

    For Each Myfile In mysource.Files
        If InStr(1, Myfile.Name, ".tiff") Then
            iCol = 1
            'Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = myFile.Path
            'iCol = iCol + 1
            Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = Myfile.Name
            iCol = iCol + 10
            Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = "1"
            'iCol = iCol + 1
            'Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = myFile.DateLastModified
            iRow = iRow + 1
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First, why are you looping through your list of files 3 times? It looks like you could nest the if statements within one loop to save time.

I am not quite sure what you are asking. Do you want the macro to list the first 30 files on sheet1 and the rest on sheet2?